# Ambiguous call to overloaded sqrt function when passing size_t

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

```
string aux;
int maxy, auxx = 0;

cin >> aux;

maxy = (int)sqrt(aux.size());
```

Why am I getting this error:

```
1> error C2668: 'sqrt' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>        could be 'long double sqrt(long double)'
1>        or       'float sqrt(float)'
1>        or       'double sqrt(double)'
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`string::size()` returns `size_t`, and `sqrt` doesn't accept it in any of its versions. So the compiler has to cast, and cannot choose to what - all of them are OK. You have to put explicit cast:

```
maxy = (int)sqrt((double)aux.size());
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that in C++, there are three functions named `sqrt` - one taking in a `float`, one taking a `double`, and one taking a `long double`.  When you try calling

```
sqrt(aux.size());
```

The compiler tries to determine which of these functions you want to call.  Since `aux.size()` returns a `string::size_type`, which is neither a `float`, `double`, nor `long double`, it tries to see if `string::size_type` is implicitly convertible to any of these three.  But since `string::size_type` is convertible to all three of these types, the compiler marks the call as ambiguous, since it's unclear which of the conversions you want to do.

To fix this, you can explicitly cast `aux.size()` to the type that you want.  For example:

```
sqrt(double(aux.size()));
```

or

```
sqrt(float(aux.size()));
```

This makes the call unambiguously match one of the two functions.  Depending on the precision you want, you can choose any of the three overloads.  Since you're just casting back to an `int`, it's probably fine to cast to a `float` here.

Comment: "An unmatched left parenthesis creates an unresolved tension that will stay with you all day" http://xkcd.com/859/ That's why I prefer C-style casts for cases like this one - they produce less levels of nesting.

Answer (score 1):

`aux.size()` returns an `std::size_t`, but `sqrt()` does not have an overloaded version that takes a `std::size_t` argument.

The compiler reports that `sqrt` has 3 overloads: which take `float`, `double` and `long double` arguments. `std::size_t` could be converted to any of those, so there's an ambiguity since the compiler doesn't know whether to convert `std::size_t` to `float` or `double` or `long double`.

Answer (score -1):

Try casting your aux.size() to one of those types, so it won't be ambiguous...