# ambiguity square root

Tags: c++, sqrt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ compiler error: ambiguous call to overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233132/c-compiler-error-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function)

just copied some code from a pdf into both C++builder XE2 and visual studio express 2012. both both compilers give error codes about ambiquity. I just started so i don't really know what to do. Maybe my textbook(pdf) is old and obsolete now? it's called "Learn c++ in 14 days". Well anyways here is the copied code.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma hdrstop
void getSqrRoot(char* buff, int x);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int x;
char buff[30];
cout << “Enter a number: “;
cin >> x;
getSqrRoot(buff, x);
cout << buff;
getch();
}
void getSqrRoot(char* buff, int x)
{
sprintf(buff, “The sqaure root is: %f”, sqrt(x));
}
```

the errorcode i got in c++builder is:

[BCC32 Error] SquareRoot.cpp(19): E2015 Ambiguity between 'std::sqrt(float) at c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\include\windows\crtl\math.h:266' and 'std::sqrt(long double) at c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\include\windows\crtl\math.h:302'
  Full parser context
    SquareRoot.cpp(18): parsing: void getSqrRoot(char *,int)

On a side note, the quotation marks in my pdf manual are different characters than the normal " which i type. these “ are also not compatible with the compiler. maybe anybody knows a fix for this as well? thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no fix you're supposed to use "..." and not whatever else is in your pdf. You could just cast your int to a double: `sqrt(static_cast<double>(x))`

Comment: I'd just make `getSqrRoot` take a `double`.

Comment: Avoid any *C++ in X period of time* book unless said period of time is "two lifetimes". There is a list of good books here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @perreal, Not even the `using namespace std;` really.

Comment: I'm surprised the supplied code doesn't give more errors, e.g. for the UNICODE quotation marks `“` around the strings.

Comment: @perreal No, _don't_ add `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Well, a book that promises you to learn C++ in 14 days is likely to propagate the use of `<stdio.h>` in C++ code or, even better, mix things like `cin` (which misses a `std::` qualification by the way) with `getch`. You should just be thankful you didn't buy this in printed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code like that:

```
void getSqrRoot(char* buff, int x)
{
 sprintf(buff, “The sqaure root is: %f”, sqrt((float)x));
}
```

Because square root is overloaded function compiler has no opportunity to implicit conversion from int x value to float or double value, you need to do it directly.

```
Compiler: see sqrt(int) -> what to choose? sqrt(float)/sqrt(double) ?
Compiler: see sqrt((float)int) -> sqrt(float), ok!
Compeler: see sqrt((double)int) -> sqrt(double), ok!
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, this compiler interpretation text is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Change your getSqrRoot Function to the below

```
void getSqrRoot(char* buff, float x)
{
```

And similarly fix the declaration in the first line.

This is happening because `std::sqrt` which is the function you are using to get the square root, can take either a `float` or a `double` but you have given it an `int` which leads to the confusion since the compiler now has no idea which function to call.